# Understanding Partitions - What can I remove?

Tags: partitioning

I recently bought a second-hand laptop that is running Ubuntu, and I want to make sure that I clear everything possible off it and then reload only what is absolutely necessary.

Currently, when I enter `sudo lsblk`, I get the following output.

```
NAME                  FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT             LABEL
sda                               465.8G                        
├─sda1                vfat          512M /boot/efi              
├─sda2                ext2          488M /boot                  
└─sda3                LVM2_member 464.8G                        
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   ext4        456.9G /                      
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap          7.9G [SWAP]
```

What is the best way to delete anything that could possibly be unsafe from the past user? What is a typical, bare-bones partition configuration for an Ubuntu machine? How do I tell if a Swap is needed and how much I should allocate for it? Can I clear everything and set up a system as described by just booting from a live Ubuntu disk?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I clear everything and set up a system as described by just booting from a live Ubuntu disk?

Yes. And that's your best option. Delete everything, reinstall the system from scratch. Don't trust an operating system left behind by another user, unless it's a trusted family member. It's very easy to install a clean Ubuntu, and you'll have the latest software, and without a shadow of a doubt of trojan horses or simply just crap left behind by the previous owner.